# How does typescript make generics mandatory?

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion

```
`export const test = <T>(a:string,{c,d} = {c: T[], D:T} = {})=>{} `
```

How does typescript make generics mandatory

I want to define a function that has a T type so that the developer must pass in the type when using it

```
test<string>()  ok
test<number>()  ok 
test()   error
```

Comment: "I want to define a function that has a `T` type so that the developer must pass in the type when using it"  This is probably an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); what is the underlying use case that you think needs to be solved by making a manually specified type argument mandatory?  Also, it would be nice to see a [mre] here; do you want your function to be called with zero arguments or with the arguments in your ... template literal string... thing... at the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable type inference, disable type inference

```
import { F } from 'ts-toolbelt'
function test<T = never>(a: string, b: F.NoInfer<T>[], c: F.NoInfer<T>) { }
//                ^ must have default, otherwise defaults to `unknown`

test('', [], '')
// function test<never>(a: string, b: never[], c: never): void

test<string>('', [''], '')
// ok
```

https://millsp.github.io/ts-toolbelt/modules/function_noinfer.html
`type NoInfer<A>: [A][A extends any ? 0 : never]`

---

If you want to prevent usage of simple arg, use

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
type NeverIfNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? never : any;

export const test = <T = never>(
    a: string & NeverIfNever<T>,
    { c, d }: { c?: NoInfer<T>[]; d?: NoInfer<T> } = {}
) => {};

test('', {})
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
```

If you have a single fn arg that's more hard, ask if needed

Comment: Thanks to my help, can it be realized without relying on ts-toolbelt?

Comment: @laterday They have the definition of `NoInfer` included.

Comment: But that doesn't seem to work. My data structure is
`export const test = <T>(a:string,{ c,d }  = { c: T[] , D:T } = {}  )=>{}`

Comment: How to make `export const test = <T>(a:string,{c,d} = {c: T[], D:T} = {})=>{} ` data structure generic T mandatory

Comment: @Dimava  Looking forward to your help.

Comment: @pink  Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Use `NoInfer<T>` instead of `T` when using it in the parameter list.

Comment: @pink  I used NoInfer<T>, but it didn't work. Could you write a demo, thank you very much   `export const test = <T>(a:string,{c,d} = {c: (data: T) => T[];, D:T} = {})=>{} `

Comment: @pink Expected to meet the requirements of test above, T is mandatory

Comment: @laterday https://tsplay.dev/wXvgQm You can't make it error on `test` itself if you don't pass a generic. You can make it error in the arguments list, like Dimava demonstrated here.

Comment: @laterday updated. If you want single {} you'll need restargs, that's more difficult

Comment: @Dimava    Thank you very much for your help. I don't have a deep understanding of ts. What is the difference between NoInfer and NeverIfNever

Comment: @laterday `NeverIfNever<T>` is `never` if T is `never`, and `any` in all other cases (it uses `[T]` hack to awoid `T=never`case of being ignored but I guess it's not really needed in this case as it would return `never` anyways). `NoInfer<T>` is 1-element array whos [0] element is selected (with a `T extends any ? 0 : never`(always 0) hack to prevent inferring)